# disposeTickMarkerX is not defined

Tags: lightningchart

I am migrating from version 3 to 4 and I am getting error for following code

```
chart[unique].setAutoCursor(cursor => cursor
    .disposeTickMarkerX());
```

I get following error ,

```
Uncaught TypeError: cursor.disposeTickMarkerX is not a function
```

I searched through change log but i cannot find anything for setAutoCursor or disposeTickMarkerX

Comment: Kindly read the migration guide https://lightningchart.com/news/releases/lightningchart-js-v-4-0/

Comment: I have used  ChartXY.setAutoCursorMode(AutoCursorModes.disabled) , is this correct